# python: list comprehension tactics

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm looking to take a string and create a list of strings that build up the original string.

e.g.:

```
"asdf" => ["a", "as", "asd", "asdf"]
```

I'm sure there's a "pythonic" way to do it; I think I'm just losing my mind. What's the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possibility:

```
>>> st = 'asdf'
>>> [st[:n+1] for n in range(len(st))]
['a', 'as', 'asd', 'asdf']
```

Comment: Be careful when using this on anything other than very short strings. A 300-character string would generate a 300-element list containing 45,150 characters!

Comment: A minor point, but I would use xrange() instead of range(), since you don't need to create the list of integers:
>>> x="asdf"
>>> [x[:n] for n in xrange(1,len(x)+1)]
['a', 'as', 'asd', 'asdf']

Answer (score 17):

If you're going to be looping over the elements of your "list", you may be better off using a generator rather than list comprehension:

```
>>> text = "I'm a little teapot."
>>> textgen = (text[:i + 1] for i in xrange(len(text)))
>>> textgen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0119BDA0>
>>> for item in textgen:
...     if re.search("t$", item):
...         print item
I'm a lit
I'm a litt
I'm a little t
I'm a little teapot
>>>
```

This code never creates a list object, nor does it ever (delta garbage collection) create more than one extra string (in addition to `text`).

Comment: Note that you get the same benefits much more simply with a simple for loop-- "for n in xrange(len(text)): do_something_with(text[:n+1])"

Comment: Generator is definitely the way to go.